# Recovery (renew, restore) the removed element

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is there any method that I can use to recovery deleted element?

This is my code for remove the element

```
myFunction() {

    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var February = document.getElementById('February');

    if(width <= 1114)
    {
      if(February != null)
      February.remove();

    }

}
```

I need restore the element when the width is more than 1114 (e.g.)

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: CSS Media Queries can do this, there is really no need to use JavaScript.

Comment: Instead of removing, you can try to hide the element, and later show it when required.

Comment: in media queries, you can do this, and then the element will disappear from the page, but it wont be deleted actually, to do that you can write another code.

Comment: I need to delete the element for resizing the page (using flax layout, when I set the element invisible, it is wrong)

Comment: You mean flex? And an element hidden with display none is having issues? That seems odd.

Comment: The div does not resize after set the element invisible. So I need remove the element, not hide ...

Comment: `document.getElementById("myP").style.visibility = "hidden";` <- I try to use this, but doesn't work

Comment: visibility maintains space!!!!! You should be using display

Comment: `document.getElementById("myP").style.display = "none";`

Comment: And then when I want to restore the element?

Comment: So you set it to block, inline-block, inline depending on what it is. but with css media, there is no need to set it back....

Comment: display:none -> display:flex/block/inline/inline-flex/inline-block whatever you want. Anything except `none` will 'restore' it. And again, do not use `javascript` if you need only to show/hide an element when the width of window changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use JavaScript. With CSS Media Queries and display:none, you can remove the element from the document. No JavaScript is needed to listen for resize events, the browser does it for you with CSS

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:1114px){
  .hide-max {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hide-max">This is hidden when under max</div>
```

Comment: Click Expand Snippet / Full Page and you can see it work.